# Not able to create new angular project optimized for mobile

Tags: angular-cli

I am following https://mobile.angular.io/guides/ link but I get struck at "ng new hello-mobile —mobile” as don’t see —mobile option available in @angular/cli: 1.3.0
Any alternative for starting prototype app using Angular2 & PWA?

Answer (score 0):

`--mobile` option has being removed from `angular-cli` a [while ago](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4143). Check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5791) for more details.

I think you must try [angular-pwa](https://github.com/Centroida/angular-pwa) and [angular-pwa-seed](https://github.com/jvitor83/angular-pwa-seed) github repos

There is a couple of more `Angular PWA` examples on github, like this one [angular2-dribbble-pwa](https://github.com/addyosmani/angular2-dribbble-pw) but they are all looking quite outdated.